# Union two SQL Queries with one same column ( using Eloquent )

Tags: laravel-5.4, eloquent

i have two queries which should be union (with laravel eloquent) but there is a duplicate column called group_date in both query and I should show one of them

```
SELECT
  to_char(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS group_date,
  COUNT(*)                                   AS successful_transaction
FROM "REPORT_EVENTS"
WHERE "RESULT_CODE" = '0' AND "EVENT_TYPE" = 'BILL'
GROUP BY to_char(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY "GROUP_DATE" DESC

SELECT
  to_char(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS group_date,
  COUNT(*)                                   AS unsuccessful_transaction
FROM "REPORT_EVENTS"
WHERE "RESULT_CODE" = '1' AND "EVENT_TYPE" = 'BILL'
GROUP BY to_char(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY "GROUP_DATE" DESC
```

Comment: What do want to achieve? Joining the above queries or get union of them?

Comment: Actually i want to get union result, at last i should have three columns 1-Group_date 2-successful_transaction 3-unsuccessful_transaction

Comment: Conceptually, the result of union has the same columns as the underlying queries but based on what you looking for as result, it seems that you need to join your queries. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @mehran The question actually is clear, and joining is also not what we want.

Comment: Thank you, The SQL Query which was written by TIM, can work all i need is to change it to Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want a `UNION` here, but rather a single query which uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS group_date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RESULT_CODE = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS successful_transaction,
    SUM(CASE WHEN RESULT_CODE = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unsuccessful_transaction
FROM "REPORT_EVENTS"
WHERE "EVENT_TYPE" = 'BILL'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CREATE_UTC_DATETIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY "GROUP_DATE" DESC
```

I am not giving any Eloquent/Laravel code here, but I am fairly certain that you would need a custom raw query to handle this.  So, your actual PHP code would more or less just have the above query in its raw form.